# A way to easily grab all the *.dll files from libraries using premake?

Tags: c++, premake

I'm starting to get familiar with premake5 for my C++ projects and I'm really loving it. One of the parts that's driving me crazy though is moving the .dll files from each folder to the target directory. For each library I have to do something along the lines of

```
postbuildcommands
{
"copy $(SolutionDir)Vendor\\SDL2\\lib\\x86\\SDL2.dll            $(SolutionDir)bin\\".._proj.name.."\\Debug\\Win32\\SDL2.dll",
}
```

For Debug and Release for x86/x64. So it starts to get cumbersome quickly. I was hoping there are better ways to accomplish this besides just going static? Any solutions would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: For SDL2 and visual, I used [`nuget`](https://premake.github.io/docs/nuget/): `filter { "action:vs*" } nuget({"sdl2.nuget:2.28.0", "sdl2.nuget.redist:2.28.0"})` (dependencies have to be added manually).

Comment: Else adding the dlls as [`files`](https://premake.github.io/docs/files/) with [`buildaction "Copy"`](https://premake.github.io/docs/buildaction) is alternative than `postbuildcommands` (that you can foactorize with proper [Tokens](https://premake.github.io/docs/Tokens/)).